# php not showing any errors & not inserting values in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

When I clicked on insert button, it is not inserting data into my main database and also not showing any error, please tell me what's the error so I can solve it.

```
<?php
require_once "header.php";
require_once "config.php";

require('SpreadsheetReader/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require('SpreadsheetReader/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

    if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType))
    {

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $name = 0;
        $company = 0;
        $package = 0;
        $status = 0;
        $uploaddate = date("Y/m/d hh:mm:ss");

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->Sheets());
        try
        {

        for($i=0; $i<$sheetCount; $i++)
        {
            $Reader->ChangeSheet(1);
            foreach($Reader as $Row)
            {
                if(isset($Row[0])) {$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Row[0]);}
                if(isset($Row[1])) { 
                    $input = $Row[1];
                    $output = substr($input, -10); 
                    $mobile=intval($output);
                }


                if(isset($Row[2])) {$company=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Row[2]);}
                if(isset($Row[3])) {$package=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Row[3]);}
                if(isset($Row[4])) {$status=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$Row[4]);}

                if (!empty($mobile)) 
                {
                    $query= "INSERT INTO MAINDATABASE (NAME, MOBILE, COMPANY, PACKAGE, STATUS, UPLOAD_DATE) 
                    VALUES ('".$name."','".$mobile."','".$company."','".$package."','".$status."','".$uploaddate."')";      
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel Data Successfully Imported into Main Database";
                    } 
                    else{
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        }
        catch (Exception $E)
        {
            echo $E -> getMessage();
        }


        //DELETE DUPLICATES FROM MAINDATABASE BECAUSE ITS ALREADY ENQUIRY
        mysqli_query($link,"DELETE a.* FROM MAINDATABASE a INNER JOIN ENQUIRY b ON a.MOBILE = b.CLINT_MOBILE");
        //DELETE DUPLICATES RECORD BECAUSE ITS ALREADY A USER
        mysqli_query($link,"DELETE a.* FROM MAINDATABASE a INNER JOIN USERS b ON a.MOBILE = b.MOBILE");
        //DELETE DUPLICATES RECORDS FROM SAME TABLE
        mysqli_query($link,"DELETE t1 FROM MAINDATABASE t1, MAINDATABASE t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.MOBILE = t2.MOBILE");
        //ARRANGE PRIMARY KEY ID IN SEQUENCE
        mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE MAINDATABASE DROP ID");
        mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE MAINDATABASE AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
        mysqli_query($link,"ALTER TABLE MAINDATABASE ADD ID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST");
    }
    else
    { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Error.. Please select Only Excel File format";
    }

mysqli_close($link);

}

?>
```

I think this problem is with my php reader but I couldn't able to solve it. I also wanted to upload case files but not getting a proper way. just let me know where is am stuck and I'll solve my problem.

Comment: did you try to echo the intval($output) ?

Comment: You should temporarily place some echo / print_r / var_dump to find out what is not working there

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @KunalRaut checked it works great. and it sholud not problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked everything and after some research i found answer. my phpexcelreader2 has some error so I changed that library to newly downloaded library and it works. thank you for your help friends.